# Embedding an image in html email using R

Tags: html, r, email, base64

I am trying to send an html image via email in R. First I tried to send the image by using following code

```
send_mail<-function(){
sender <- "asasa<support@aa.com>"
recipients <- c("aasb@aa.com", "asab@aa.com", "asb@aa.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
        to = recipients,
        subject = paste0("Send mail with image"),
        body <- <html><img src="../img.png"></html>,
        smtp = list(host.name = "XX", port = XX,
                    user.name = "XXX@gmail.com",            
                    passwd = "XXX", ssl = TRUE),
        authenticate = TRUE,
        html = TRUE,
        send = TRUE)
}
send_mail()
```

The mail was sent but no image was being shown. I searched again and then decided to use base64 to embedd the image and then send the mail by using following code

```
library(RCurl)
txt <- base64enc::base64encode("abc_2018-11-27.png")
html1 <- sprintf('<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"></body></html>', txt)
send_mail<-function(){
sender <- "asasa<support@aa.com>"
recipients <- c("aasb@aa.com", "asab@aa.com", "asb@aa.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
    to = recipients,
    subject = paste0("Send mail with image"),
    body <-  html1,
    smtp = list(host.name = "XX", port = XX,
                user.name = "XXX@gmail.com",            
                passwd = "XXX", ssl = TRUE),
    authenticate = TRUE,
    html = TRUE,
    send = TRUE)
 }
send_mail()
```

So once again mail was send in gmail only the base64 code was visible in the mail body while in outlook there was just an icon missing image.

Any idea what the issue here or how can I send an html image in mail. The images are on local system.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
    body <- <html><img src="../img.png"></html>,
```

to

```
    body = paste0('<html><img src="../img.png"></html>'),
```

and you have it